# Adaption code from python 3 to 2, super().__init__()

Tags: python, django

I'm going through Test Driven Development with Python book. But decided to use Python2 instead of Python version 3. In the end of chapter 12 form.py code in book was like (python3):

```
class ExistingListItemForm(ItemForm):

    def __init__(self, for_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instance.list = for_list


    def validate_unique(self):
        try:
            self.instance.validate_unique()
        except ValidationError as e:
            e.error_dict = {'text': [DUPLICATE_ITEM_ERROR]}
            self._update_errors(e)
```

My code (python2):

```
class ExistingListItemForm(ItemForm):

    def __init__(self, for_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExistingListItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instance.list = for_list

    def validate_unique(self):
        try:
            self.instance.validate_unique()
        except ValidationError as e:
            e.error_dict = {'text': [DUPLICATE_ITEM_ERROR]}
            self._update_errors(e)
```

Still got error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

**UPDATE:**
ItemForm:

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('text',)
        widgets = {
            'text': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Enter a to-do item',
            'class': 'form-control input-lg',
            }),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'text': {'required': EMPTY_LIST_ERROR}
        }

    def save(self, for_list):
        self.instance.list = for_list
        return super(ItemForm, self).save()
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trytec/Desktop/projects/TDD/superlists/lists/tests/test_views.py", line 150, in test_redirects_after_POST
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/lists/%d/' % (new_list.id, ))
  File "/home/trytec/Desktop/virts/TDD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 295, in assertRedirects
    secure=(scheme == 'https'))
  File "/home/trytec/Desktop/virts/TDD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 467, in get
    **extra)
  File "/home/trytec/Desktop/virts/TDD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 285, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
  File "/home/trytec/Desktop/virts/TDD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 355, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/home/trytec/Desktop/virts/TDD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 437, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/trytec/Desktop/virts/TDD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/trytec/Desktop/projects/TDD/superlists/lists/views.py", line 17, in view_list
    form = ExistingListItemForm()
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: How did you instantiate `ExistingListItemForm`?

Comment: Can you show ItemForm?

Comment: @AlexLisovoy added ItemForm to the post

Comment: Please show the full traceback as well.

Comment: @Evert done, in open post

Comment: Well the traceback says it: the error is on line 17 of views.py, where you give no arguments to ExistingListItemForm().

Comment: @trytec You should provide for_list arg like in book: form = ExistingListItemForm(for_list=list_)

Comment: Nothing to do with going from 3 to 2, or with `__init__()`; as people say above: `for_list` is a mandatory argument, which you don't provide. *And this is really why you should always provide a full traceback*.

Comment: @AlexLisovoy помогло, спасибо. Видимо, пропустил

Comment: Problem's solved, miss argument in view.py. Thanks, everyone